# How to run update spec with custom route, strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, strong-parameters

I have a controller with the following strong params defined:

```
def create_params
  params.require(:foo).permit(:zip_code)
end
```

The route (I am not able to refactor this route right now, and there's an update record at the same endpoint.)

`patch '/foos/:foo_id' => 'foos#update'`

I'm trying to write a spec that updates the `foo`'s `zipcode`.

```
context "zip code is not in list of valid zip codes" do
     it "returns status code 5 - Zipcode not allowed" do
        params = { foo: {zip_code: "WORDS"} }
        patch "foos/:foo_id", foo_id: foo.id, params.to_json, format: :json
        r = parse(response)
        expect(r["status_code"]).to eq(5)
     end
end
```

I've tried a million ways to format the patch call correctly including converting foo to a hash.  How can I format the request appropriately?

Comment: what's the error that you're getting with the above?

Comment: hang on... why are you literally converting the params into json? You don't need to do that - just pass the params as a ruby hash. Think of it this way: once you're inside your controller - Rails has already converted any json to the ordinary ruby params hash... so your controller specs should act that way too. ie just use `patch "foos/:foo_id", foo_id: foo.id, { foo: {zip_code: "WORDS"} }, format: :json`